# Color Camera Auto Exposure not working in Java

Tags: google-project-tango

In addition to the posts about Project Tango's color camera configs (auto exposure, iso and exposure time) not working in C or Unity, it also appears that the configs do not work in Java either.

Here is the code I've added to the basic java_video_overlay_example function "startCameraPreview":

```
// Connect to color camera
tangoCameraPreview.connectToTangoCamera(mTango, TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
// Use default configuration for Tango Service.
TangoConfig config = mTango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);

// New Line:
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORMODEAUTO, false);

mTango.connect(config);
mIsConnected = true;
```

I'm pretty sure this is how the configs are supposed to be set. Has anyone else had the same issue, or been able to access exposure controls through Tango's Java SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, it might help you further

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483336/how-to-set-the-tango-camera-exposure-and-iso-parameters-from-c-unity
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. Unfortunately the Project Tango SDK overrides normal android camera control. The camera configs need to be accessed through the Tango config functions in order to work properly.